# Use QQuickView or QQmlApplicationEngine to switch between pages from ApplicationWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qquickview, qqmlapplicationengine

I'd like to use an `ApplicationWindow` as a main file and be able to switch to other `QML` files from `C++` with `QQuickView::setSource(const QUrl & url)`. Basically it would do this:

start-up => loads **main.qml** (`ApplicationWindow`) => click on help button => `C++` loads **help.qml** file => etc.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    CustomQQuickView view;

    view.setSource(QUrl{"qrc:/main.qml"});
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Loader
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: mainPageLoader
    }

    Button
    {
        text: "Help"
        onClicked: { mainPageLoader.source = "help.qml"}
    }
}
```

(I am wondering if the `Loader` here is really necessary here)

However `QQuickView` only supports loading of root objects that derive from `QQuickItem`. Therefore it doesn't work with `ApplicationWindow`.

I'm thinking about using `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead of `QQuickView` but the usage seems different, this class being only equipped with `QQmlApplicationEngine::load(const QUrl & url)`

What would be the best course of action for my purpose? Do I really need an `ApplicationWindow` in my **main.qml** file?

Comment: The usual course of events is: action in QML context -> computation in c++ -> update in the QML context, according to the computation result. There are several ways to pass data between C++ and QML and you can use a `StackView` to switch between different views. So, why bother loading a different QML from C++?

Comment: The whole idea of the QML is to use the C++, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QQmlApplicationEngine` as you suggest, and with the `main.qml` as you say, but set a context property from C++ with the content page URL, e.g. `help.qml` - then bind to this context property in the Loader's source property.

This is the normal way of controlling QML from C++ - expose context properties or singleton objects with properties, drive them from C++, and have QML bindings respond to changes.

Comment: Code example please!