# About loading main.qml from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying for Loading Qml From c++ file.
How to load qml file from c++ .
It is by default loaded from main.cpp file but i want to load it from my class (e.g MyClass => user define class).

My code is here

1) main.cpp

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
MyClass tr;
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/App/main.qml"));
viewer.showExpanded();
tr.setApplication(&app,&viewer);
```

2) MyClass.cpp

```
setApplication(QGuiApplication *a,QtQuick2ApplicationViewer *v)

{

    this->app = app;
    this->viewer = viewer;    
}

// This loadQmlFile() slot I have called from qml using signal
```

3) loadQmlFile function

```
void MyClass::loadQmlFile() 

{

// code for changing qml here

 viewer->setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/App/main.qml"));

}
```

But program getting crashed. Please help me how to load Qml from c++

Comment: Similar to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35487237/5695504

Comment: Tushar, welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please, give us Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable application (as in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you.

Comment: its minimal,complete and verifiable application. I did not get what you want more in that? simple i call MyClass::setApplication(QGuiApplication *a,QtQuick2ApplicationViewer *v)  from main.cpp and loading main.qml again in MyClass::loadQmlFile()  function. but program crashes means terminate.

Comment: Not similar llya . Its different.